# (ilink32 Error) Fatal: Unable to open file 'b:\c' - C++ Builder

Tags: linker-errors, c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

I am making a small project for uni, and i've been stuck on this issue. Whenever i try to run my project, it keeps giving me this error. I don't know what kind of file this even is, and i certaintly can't find it anywhere.

I've tried moving the project elsewhere and letting the builder rebuild all the extra files, i've cleared out any temp files and reran it, i've searched my entire code and the file isn't mentioned once. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using? "*i've searched my entire code and the file isn't mentioned once*" - Did you search for `b:\c` inside your project's main `.bpr`/`.cbproj` file itself?

Comment: I am using C++ Builder 11 Community Edition, and yes, i have searched inside all of my project files that i could have feasibly opened with notepad++. Nothing came up. I don't know if this is important, but i suppose i should mention it, the folder is in my B: drive.

Comment: Can you provide the complete error message? Do you get the same error on a fresh project?

Comment: That is the complete error message which is why im very confused about what's happening. I hadn't thought of trying it on a completely fresh project, but now that i've checked, i get the same error even on completely empty new projects.

Comment: If you use a tool like [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), is `b:\c` really the *complete* path that the linker is looked for? Or is the path being truncated in the error message?

Comment: I am copy-pasting the entire error and do not use any outside tools, and if it is truncated, i don't know how to untruncate it. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the entire program, but the error message is still here.

Comment: "*[I] do not use any outside tools*" - I'm suggesting that you SHOULD use an external tool, to verify that the path actually being looked for by the file system matches the path in the error message.  If they do match, then you have a configuration problem somewhere in your project. If they don't match, then you have an IDE bug in its display of the path in the error message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've tried out the tool you've given me, and the project is attempting to create a file with the path B:\c , but can't for some reason. Under result it says "Name not found". If there is anything you could tell me from this information i would be very greatful, as i am already for your previous help.

Comment: Then you neeed to keep looking in your project files, *something* is referencing this `c` file incorrectly. If you still can't find it, then contact Embarcadero Support for help, since you can reproduce it with new projects.

Comment: What files are in your project?